# Web service is not working on GlassFish

Tags: java, axis

I am generating web service client in Eclipse Helios by Axis 1.4 version. The client stubs are working fine as per the expectation by using local main programs, but when I deploy the stub and application on GlassFish server, I am getting the following exception:

Edited : Now it gives exception like this ..

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: WEB9031: WebappClassLoader unable to load resource [META-INF/services/org.apache.axis.EngineConfigurationFactory], because it has not yet been started, or was already stopped
    at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.findResourceInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:2074)
    at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.findResource(WebappClassLoader.java:1034)
    at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.getResource(WebappClassLoader.java:1169)
```

Can anyone tell me why it is happening?

Its happening only when I deploy the application on GlassFish server.

Thanks,
Gunjan.

Comment: Do you have any JAX-RPC or AXIS related jars into your shared domain ext folder?

Comment: Just out of curiosity: Do you have specific reasons for using Axis 1.4? It's quite old. If you want to use Axis, why not Axis 2?

Comment: @ Paulius : No.. I have added axis.jar,xml-rpc.jar nad jax-rpc.jar in GlassFish server's lib directory. Its not in domain's EXT directory.

Comment: @ joergl : I am using Eclipse Helios J2EE IDE. In this IDE, when I choose AXIS 2 for stub generation it give error like "The Apache Axis2 Web service runtime in GlassFish 3.1 does not support the client project JAXB Generated tub2."

Comment: Well, then try to remove axis.jar,xml-rpc.jar nad jax-rpc.jar from the global classpath and add then only to your application, this might be the problem, I have used axis 1.4 successfully with glassfish, but all framework libs I kept in the lib folder of my application, not in the global classpath. This might be the problem. Try it and let us know if it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3532262/cant-redeploy-war-that-uses-axis-in-glassfish-3) refers to the similar problem you have. So as I mention in my comment, remove all Axis related stuff from global `glassfish` classpath, add them into your application and it should all be fine.

It is not a very good practice to keep framework specific libraries in the server global libraries. In the global classpath should go libs like JDBC, logging frameworks, but not WS stack specific libraries.

Comment: @ Paulius Matulionis : yeah ...its working fine .. after removing AXIS.jar from server global directory and domain'ext directory. Here make note that in domain's ext, i need to addd jax.wsdl.jar file.

Comment: @ Paulius Matulionis : my friend suggested me to ser "delegate" attribute to false in sun-web.xml file. For example it will be like this : <class-loader delegate="true"/>. I dont know when to use  sun-web.xml. I want your suggestion. Is it related to my issue ? Can this property help to solve this issue ?

Comment: I don't know what <class-loader delegate="true"/> is, I've never used it before. But as I said, the WS framework related libraries has to come within application, I am sure of it.